# powershell or excel split string at last two commas in the string

Tags: regex, string, excel, powershell, split

I have a list of file shares (hundreds of thousands of lines) and most align perfectly in excel and I can use text to columns to split.  But I'm having an issue because there are a number of file paths that have a comma in the name and it is splitting there instead of the actual desired delimiter.  Here is an example of the strings:

```
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm,DOMAIN\YA-MGD              ,               RWXD      
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm,DOMAIN\SGRP-Triple,               RWXD
```

in the above two lines beginning at \\Share it is splitting at Jones and ",DOMAIN" and then the last comma leaving the full share path in tact.   the number of commas can vary up to 4 or 5.  I only want it to split at the last two commas.  How can I programmatically do that?  An excel formula or powershell script would be ideal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex` to split on the last occurrence of `,`, twice:

```
$String = '\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm,DOMAIN\YA-MGD              ,               RWXD      '
$Remainder,$Last = $String -split ',(?=[^,]*$)' |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()}
$First,$Middle   = $Remainder -split ',(?=[^,]*$)' |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()}
```

Resulting in:

```
PS C:\> $First,$Middle,$Last
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm
DOMAIN\YA-MGD
RWXD
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I was able to build my script off of that.  Here was my final build which is clunky but works :)

Comment: $a = Select-String -Pattern "\w" -Path C:\temp\Excel\test.txt


$a | foreach {$string = $_.line; $Remainder,$Last = $String -split ',(?=[^,]*$)' |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()};$First,$Middle   = $Remainder -split ',(?=[^,]*$)' |ForEach-Object {$_.Trim()}; $f = $first + ";" + $Middle + ";" + $Last; $f | Out-File C:\temp\Excel\final.txt -Append}

Comment: @user3566325 awesome :) If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it on the left

Comment: Thanks.  this is my first post to stackoverflow and was trying to figure that out :)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell and RegEx can do it. Here's the link to explain the RegEx:

https://regex101.com/r/eW2rP5/2

The RegEx that I will use is `^(.+?),([^,]+?),([^,]*)$`. That gets everything from the beginning of the line up to the second to the last comma, skipping the comma, then all non-comma characters up to the last comma, skipping the comma again, and all non-comma characters to the end of the line. Each is it's own capture group, so we can use the automatic `$Matches` variable to make a PSCustomObject with properties for each section as such:

```
@"
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm,DOMAIN\YA-MGD              ,               RWXD      
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - $671.16 - 5-16-14.xlsm,DOMAIN\SGRP-Triple,               RWXD 
"@ -split "`r`n"|Where{$_ -match "^(.+?),([^,]+?),([^,]*)$"}|ForEach{[PSCustomObject]@{"SharePath"=$Matches[1];"User"=$Matches[2].trim();"Rights"=$Matches[3].trim()}}
```

The magic is in the combination of the `Where` statement where it matches for the RegEx, and the `ForEach` loop that uses those matches to create a custom object for each line. You end up with:

```
SharePath                                                                                                                   User               Rights
---------                                                                                                                   ----               ------
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - .16 - 5-16-14.xlsm DOMAIN\YA-MGD      RWXD  
\\\Share\MMMC\MMMC\Employees\Jones, Pat\Payment Vouchers\The Creative Group\Amy DOE\2014\Inv. # 403412 - .16 - 5-16-14.xlsm DOMAIN\SGRP-Triple RWXD
```

Comment: Thank for the info. I'm going to squirrel this away!  I appreciate the help!